# Erlang receive and after

Tags: erlang, reverse-engineering, ctf

```erlang
p(M, C, B, I) when B =:= 32#3J ->
    receive {_} -> a
    after 27#5C ->
        C ! { self(), { M, (B * 13#37) rem 35#7B, I }} end;
```

This is a part of code that expects input. I understand that it needs to look like `(num,num,115,num)` to pass the first part, but I don't understand what happens after that with the `receive` and the `after` part, can anybody explain?

I tried reading documentation of erlang and just couldn't understand that part of the code.

Comment: and where does that "a after.." even mean? where does a come from?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what a [receive expression](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#receive) looks like:

```
receive
    Pattern1 [when GuardSeq1] ->
        Body1;
    ...;
    PatternN [when GuardSeqN] ->
        BodyN
after
    ExprT ->
        BodyT
end
```

In erlang, a `receive` waits for a message to be sent to the process executing the receive. The message has to match a Pattern, in your case`{_}`, for the Body of the matching clause to execute (otherwise the receive waits indefinitely for a matching message).  The term `{_}` matches any message that consists of a tuple, `{}`, with a single term inside the tuple, `_`.  The notation `_` matches anything, so the tuple could contain a nested tuple, a list, a string, a number...anything.  So, the tuple `{[1,a,"hello"]}` would match, but not the tuple `{a, 2}`.

`receive..after` works exactly as receive, except that if no matching message has arrived within ExprT milliseconds, then BodyT is evaluated instead.

Here's your code:

```
p(M, C, B, I) when B =:= 32#3J -> 
    receive 
        {_} -> 
            a 
    after 27#5C -> 
        C ! { self(), { M, (B * 13#37) rem 35#7B, I }} 
end;
```

Integers can be expressed in the format:  [base#value](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#number), and `27#5C` is the same as the decimal number 147.

In this line:

```
C ! { self(), { M, (B * 13#37) rem 35#7B, I }}
```

the variable `C` will contain a process identifier, called a "pid" in erlang, and the operator `!` sends a message to the process specified on the left hand side.  The right had side is the message that is sent to process `C`, which in this case is a tuple containing the current process identifier, `self()`, as the first term, and another tuple as the second term.

Your code consists of a function that contains a receive statement, where the receive has a 147 millisecond timeout.  After the `receive` line executes, if there's a message currently in the process  mail box that matches `{_}` or if the process receives a message that matches `{_}` within the next 147 milliseconds, then the function returns the atom `a`, otherwise the function sends a message to another process and returns the same message--because `!` returns the right hand side.

In erlang, you can easily start 1 million processes on a basic laptop, and the processes can send each other messages and the processes can receive particular messages and execute code in response to those messages.

Comment: can i send you a private dm about something in erlang?